# Unable to compile Linux kernel on cygwin using i686-pc-linux-gnu-

Tags: linux, cygwin

I am working on compiling Linux kernel on cygwin, I got above tool chain from below path.
    https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-06/msg00221.html

```
I exported the toolchain path. and ran
**make defconfig**
**make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE=i686-pc-linux-gnu- menuconfig**
**make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE=i686-pc-linux-gnu- -j4**
Running above command gave me below error, i need to add any patches to this linux kernel

scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/empty.o' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CC      kernel/bounds.s
Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
Makefile:980: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:555: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Thanks steven, we already compiled Linux on virtual box. But we are having a proprietary tool which is eclipse based, which have installation permissions only on windows, So i am trying to do it in windows or else is there any possible way to connect to ubuntu machine from eclipse so that i can map the ubuntu folder to windows using samba and can compile linux from tool itself, which implicitly compiles on ubuntu machine.